# How to split a string date(from Database) into year, month and day

Tags: php, cakephp

Hi I have the following php event

```
public function onRenderDate(Event $event, $propertyValue)
{
    // $propertyValue will be something like 1970-01-01,need to split the value in to following format
    pr($propertyValue);
    pr(getType($propertyValue));

    $arr = [
        'year' => 2016,
        'month' => 07,
        'day' => 01
    ];

    return $arr;
}
```

Now I hardcoded the $arr, how can I split my $propertyValue(which returns a string date (2016-10-05T00:00:00+00:00)) in to the $arr, so that I can get each individual values like that? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version! In CakePHP 3.x, date values from the database would be objects, given that you are using the proper column types. **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function onRenderDate(Event $event, $propertyValue)
{
    $time = strtotime( $propertyValue);
    $newformat = date('Y-m-d',$time);
    $newformatArr = explode('-',$newformat);


        $arr = [
            'year' => $newformatArr[0],
            'month' => $newformatArr[1],
            'day' => $newformatArr[2]
        ];

    return $arr;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using strtotime() php function. The function expects to be given a string containing an English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp. Using timestamp, you can get day, month and year using date() function. Below i have update your function.

```
public function onRenderDate(Event $event, $propertyValue)
{
    $timestamp = strtotime( $propertyValue);

        $arr = [
            'year' => date('Y', $timestamp),
            'month' => date('m', $timestamp),
            'day' => date('d', $timestamp)
        ];

    return $arr;

}
```